# Add class when X class is been removed via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, slide

I am trying to add a class to a div when another class is been removed with JS.

This is my HTML:

```
<body class="homepage">

<div id="wrap">

    <div id="projects">
      <section id="project-0" class="slide active"> Slide 1</section>
      <section id="project-1" class="slide active"> Slide 2</section>
      <section id="project-2" class="slide active"> Slide 3</section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content"> Website main content </div>
```

This is a vertical slide, so when you scroll down, the `active` class is removed with JS. What I want to achieve is to add a class to `body` when the `active` is removed from `project-2`.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't recognise the class `active` because it's been added via JS...

```
if(!$("#project-2").hasClass("active")){
    $("body").addClass("shifted");
 }
```

JS:

```
var delta = 0;
var currentSlideIndex = 0;
var scrollThreshold = 30;
var slides = $(".slide");
var numSlides = slides.length;
function elementScroll (e) {
  console.log (Math.abs(delta));
  // --- Scrolling up ---
  if (e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) { 

    delta--;

    if ( Math.abs(delta) >= scrollThreshold) {
    prevSlide();
    }
  }

  // --- Scrolling down ---
  else {

    delta++;

    if (delta >= scrollThreshold) {
      nextSlide();
    }
  }

  // Prevent page from scrolling
  return false;
}


function showSlide() {

  // reset
  delta = 0;

  slides.each(function(i, slide) {
    $(slide).toggleClass('active', (i >= currentSlideIndex));
  });

}


function prevSlide() {

  currentSlideIndex--;

  if (currentSlideIndex < 0) {
    currentSlideIndex = 0;
  }

  showSlide();
}

function nextSlide() {

  currentSlideIndex++;

  if (currentSlideIndex > numSlides) { 
    currentSlideIndex = numSlides;
  }

  showSlide();
}

$(window).on({
  'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': elementScroll
});
```

[You can see here how it works](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJupc)
Thanks

Comment: Please include all relevant code, like the part that remove active when you scroll

Comment: its not possible via this approach. Better you look into vertical slider documentation and check events supported by it. almost all popular slider/carousal supports it. the events we need to target are like slide deactivate or something similar to it.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to: http://www.hugeinc.com/ but I can't find the way to make it work like them...

Comment: @patie do you know which JS code is removing `active` class? please share that here.

Comment: @vijayP Added the JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your JS code I believe you want to add `class` to `body` while scrolling down. You may try below code:

```
function prevSlide() {

    currentSlideIndex--;

    if(currentSlideIndex == (numSlides-1))
    {
        $("body").removeClass("shifted"); // remove the class from body
    }
    if (currentSlideIndex < 0) {
        currentSlideIndex = 0;
    }

    showSlide();
}

function nextSlide() {

    currentSlideIndex++;

    if (currentSlideIndex > numSlides) { 
        currentSlideIndex = numSlides;

        $("body").addClass("shifted"); // add the class to body

    }

    showSlide();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am starting with JS, so I don't know how to fix it... but your code is not working for me...

Comment: @patie - could you please check https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvepVr. Its modified a bit than this answer. for `.shifted` I have added a background color as yellow for testing purpose

Comment: You are right! I did it wrong. And could you help me with the last thing? I pasted some content here:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvepVr but it is not scrollable, do you know why?

Comment: codepen.io/anon/pen/QvepVr is my version of code. Your changes will not get saved till the time you click on Fork button. The url will change a bit by which we can say that code got saved

Comment: Sorry, I pasted your link. Is this one: https://codepen.io/palomatiessen/pen/eWqWVp

Comment: on mouse wheel scroll; its getting scrolled. But you need to scroll a lot to go to next slide. Try it

Comment: yes. i saw it. kind of trick issue with CSS. unable to think of solution to it

Answer (score 0):

Your check for the absence of the class is only started once. You had to do this with an interval from 100 ms or whatever you want:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    if (!$("#project-2").hasClass("active")){
        $("body").addClass("shifted");
    }
}, 100);
```